# gem issue when using sudo

Tags: ruby, sudo

I have made a script that is already working properly in my development environment with RVM. This script reads *.eml files and parses them.

Now, my problem is this. When I transfer it to the production server, it gives a `Permission denied - filename.eml (Errno::EACCES)` when reading some files. When I manually read these files using `sudo nano filename.eml`, it is readable so I thought running my ruby script with sudo is the answer.

But when I tried running it with `sudo ruby scriptname.rb`, this time it gives me a `cannot load such file -- mail (LoadError)`.

The mail gem is clearly installed and is shown both in `gem list --local` and `sudo gem list --local`.

The ruby versions are identical with or without sudo (1.9.3).

The mail gem is also accessible using `sudo irb` then typing `require 'mail'`.

Both development and production environments are on a Mac OS with RVM-managed ruby versions.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I found my answer to be simply to use `rvmsudo ruby scriptname.rb`. Don't know why it works but it does.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the gem is not readable for your server user, such as 'wwwroot', so please make sure the file is 775 mode. e.g.

1. cd $GEM_HOME
2. sudo chmod 755 -R .

then everything is readable for other group's users.

Comment: It is readable. Like I said, I can use `sudo irb` and then `require 'mail'` and it works.